# One to Many Data binding journey custom activity

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, custom-activity

Entry DE has the following values

```
SubscriberKey EmailAddress Offer
1             a@b.com      1234
1             a@b.com      1235
```

I created an attribute group that ties up (many)SubscriberKey to (1)Contact Key. And

```
"inArguments": [
{ "SubscriberKey":"{{Contact.Attribute.Entry_DE.SubscriberKey}}"},
{ "Offer": "{{Contact.Attribute.Entry_DE.Offer}}"}
]
```

But the results were:

```
{ SubscriberKey: '1' },
{ Offer: '1234' }

{ SubscriberKey: '1' },
{ Offer: '1234' }
```

How can I pass 'Offer attribute dynamically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing Journey (formerly Event) Data rather than Contact Data would help in your case. If you need to use Contact Data, you need to add a unique value to event data which can then be used to retrieve the correct value from the data extension within your custom activity (or you might use a custom entry event with this value as transaction key so lookup should work for contact data).

**For Event Data the expression would look like this:**

```
{{Event.<YOUR ENTRY EVENT's DEFINITION KEY>.Offer}}
```

**Further reading:**

- [Salesforce Marketing Cloud - Custom Event with Transaction Key](https://github.com/mslabina/sfmc-customevent-with-transactionkey)
- [Journey Settings](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/journey_builder/interaction_settings/)
- [Create Unique Journey Results using Transaction Keys](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-app-development.meta/mc-app-development/transaction-key.htm)
- [How Data Binding Works](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/how-data-binding-works.htm)

Comment: Hi @markus I'm using the email audience entry. Not sure how to get the entry event definition key.

Comment: Just go to your journey in Journey Builder and check out the summary of your Entry Event (either it is shown directly in the entry event on your canvas or you need to click on the header saying "ENTRY EVENT" and go to the summary page of the wizard). There you should find "EVENT DEFINITION KEY" and your key below.

Comment: I'm not using an Event Entry for the journey, I'm using the Email Audience Entry which doesnt display the definition key on summary :(

Comment: Then you could build your expression for data binding inside your custom activity using the response of "requestedInteractionDefaults" event. How this is done is described here: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/185963/36218